# The submit button is not displayed [JsonForm library]

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using JsonForm library ( https://github.com/jsonform/jsonform ) to describe a form in html and I have defined the schema and form of the JsonForm structure, but "onSubmit" function that enables the send button does not work. The button does not appear.

My code in javascript is the following (data.js)   :

```
$('#myForm').jsonForm({
    schema: {
        Min: {
            type: 'integer',
            title: 'Minimo(%):',
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,

        },
        Max: {
            type: 'number',
            title: 'Máximo (%):',
            minimum: 0,
            maximum: 100,
        }
    },
    form: [
           {
               key:'Min',
               type:'number',
               htmlClass: 'col-md-2'
           }

           ],
           onSubmit: function (errors, values){
               if (errors) {
                   alert(errors);
               }
               else {
                   document.getElementById("selectedComponents").innerHTML = "it works";
               }
           }
});
```

My html is defined as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>web</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/bootstrapCss/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" style="text/css" href="css/newCss.css" />
</head>
<body onLoad="createInitOptions()">


        <br>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 text-center" id="selectedComponents">


        </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-5 text-center">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4"  id="component">

                <div class="form-group">

                <form id="myForm"></form>

                <div id="res" class="alert">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsv.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jsonform.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/data.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Look again at the code in the playground, found here: https://jsonform.github.io/jsonform/playground/index.html now, look at yours again - notice you only have one object in the form array, yet the example has a second - one whose words match that shown on the button.;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a definition for the submit or "*" in the "form" section, and move the "onSubmit" outside to the root.

```
{
  "schema": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Email",
      "required": true,
      "maxLength": 128
    },
    "password": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "Password",
      "required": true,
      "maxLength": 128
    },
    "remember": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": true
    }
  },
  "form": [
    {
      "key": "email",
      "type": "email"
    },
    {
      "key": "password",
      "type": "password"
    },
    {
      "key": "remember",
      "inlinetitle": " Remember me",
      "notitle": true
    },
    {
      "type": "submit",
      "title": "Login"
    }
  ],

  "onSubmit": (errors, values) => {
    console.info(errors, values);
  }
}
```

I use that to my advantange, storing the form setup in a json file (without the "onSubmit") and then adding the onSubmit via javascript.

```
                var schema = await $.get("/parts/model.login.json");

                schema.onSubmit = (errors, values) => {
                    LoginResults = values;
                    LoginNext = true;
                };
```